# Gatling - Scala (How to solve "Can't cast attribute ' cursorID' of type class java.lang.String into class scala.Option?)

Tags: scala, pagination, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

Gatling - Scala (How to solve "Can't cast attribute ' cursorID' of type class java.lang.String into class scala.Option?)

I am executing cursor based pagination scripts -  looping for millions of data
but I receive errors at attributes
such as `.check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor").saveAs("TestCursorID"))`
and at `.doWhile(session => session("CursorID").as[Option[String]].isDefined)`

```
.exec(http("Test:Generate Cursor ID")
.get("/test")
.queryParam("sortField", "ID")
.queryParam("limit", 100)
.queryParam("cursor", "")
.check(status.is(200))
.check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor").saveAs("TestCursorID"))

)

.doWhile(session => session("CursorID").as[Option[String]].isDefined) {
exec(http("Test:Cursor Pagination")
.get("/test")
.queryParam("sortField", "ID")
.queryParam("limit", 100)
.queryParam("cursor", "#{TestCursorID}")
.check(status.is(200))
.check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor").optional.saveAs("CursorID"))
)
}
```

I am receiving below error
Please help me with error solving

````
12:49:53.969 [gatling-1-6] 
DEBUG io.gatling.commons.validation.package$ - j.l.ClassCastException:
Can’t cast attribute ‘CursorID’ ‘QUZURVI6aWQ6MDAwMDAwMTAtMDAwMC0wMDEwLTAwMDUtMDAwMDAwMDQ4MzIx’ of
type class java.lang.String into class scala.Option
java.lang.ClassCastException:
Can’t cast attribute ‘CursorID’ ‘QUZURVI6aWQ6MDAwMDAwMTAtMDAwMC0wMDEwLTAwMDUtMDAwMDAwMDQ4MzIx’ of
type class java.lang.String into class scala.Option
at io.gatling.commons.util.LowPriorityTypeCaster$$anon$1.cast(TypeHelper.scala:58)
at io.gatling.commons.util.TypeHelper$.cast(TypeHelper.scala:320)
at io.gatling.core.session.SessionAttribute.as(Session.scala:47)
at CursorBasedPaginationScript.CursorPaginationOnTestScenarioSimulation.$anonfun$scn$3
(CursorPaginationOnTestScenarioSimulation.scala:94)
at io.gatling.core.session.package$RichExpression$.$anonfun$safe$extension$1(package.scala:49)
at io.gatling.commons.validation.package$.safely(package.scala:30)
at io.gatling.core.session.package$RichExpression$.$anonfun$safe$1(package.scala:49)
at io.gatling.core.action.builder.LoopBuilder.$anonfun$build$1(LoopBuilder.scala:49)
at io.gatling.core.session.LoopBlock$.continue(Block.scala:38)
at io.gatling.core.action.InnerLoop.execute(Loop.scala:83)
at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang(Action.scala:41)
at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang$(Action.scala:38)
at.... ```

Expected the cursor ID should be taken and looped in the do while condition
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `CursorID` is the type of `Option[String]`?

Your log contains the line:  `Can’t cast attribute ‘CursorID’ ‘...’ of type class java.lang.String into class scala.Option`

---

Try just `String`:

```scala
session("CursorID").as[String]...
```

Or simplier:

```
session.contains("CursorID")
```